# Django - inject context into base.html

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to inject context(`single_well_info`) into my **base.html**. Base is extended by **contextual_main.html**

**views.py**

```
class ContextualMain_DetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'contextual_main.html'
    context_object_name = 'single_well_info'
    model = models.WellInfo
```

**context_processor.py**

```
from contextual.views import ContextualMain_DetailView

def add_context_to_base(request):

    return {'single_well_info': # context instance}
```

When `ContextualMain_DetailView.as_view()` is called, a model class instance `single_well_info` is injected into **contextual_main_html**

I decided to create a `context_processor` to inject this exact same context into **base.html**

How can I modify my context_processor.py to get the exact same model class instance `single_well_info` inside `ContextualMain_DetailView` ??

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but did you add your context_processor into the `TEMPLATES.OPTIONS` in settings.py ?
Also, the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) says : _Context processors are applied on top of context data. This means that a context processor may overwrite variables you’ve supplied to your Context or RequestContext, so take care to avoid variable names that overlap with those supplied by your context processors._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One go-to solution, you could define a `block` in base.html that you can extend in the child template `contextual_main.html` and then have the ability to use that same model instance. For reference, template inheritance can be read up on here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

So let's say you need `single_well_info` in base.html because you want to display it as the page title, and the page title is defined in base.html. Do something like this:

base.html:

`{% block title %} My Title {% endblock %}`

contextual_main.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} {{ single_well_info }} {% endblock %}
```

Now you have the ability to overwrite anything in `base.html` from its child template, and you have access to that context variable. You don't have to touch context_processors.py!